# Remove Duplicate Texts in a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my temp table I have a column for a list of email addresses which might be repeated. For example:

```
Row#1: test@gmail.com; test@gmail.com; test@yahoo.com; abc@gmail.com
Row#2: abc@yahoo.com; abcde@yahoo.com; abcde@yahoo.com
```

Desired Results:

```
Row#1: test@gmail.com; test@yahoo.com; abc@gmail.com
Row#2: abc@yahoo.com; abcde@yahoo.com
```

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL Server language?

Comment: maybe, but it will be a PITA. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I believe we are on SQL 2017

Comment: Can you load the temp table differently, so that this doesn't happen? Dealing with it after the fact like this will be ugly.

Comment: I'm combining email addresses from different columns. Some duplicates already eliminated because I do some UNION. But can't help if certain values are already the same..

Comment: Why not use a NOT EXISTS or a distinct? But by far the best approach would be to stop using delimited lists like this. They violate 1NF and cause all sorts of pain like what you are facing.

Answer (score 7):

Well, assuming SQL Server 2017, and that you have a key column (or combination of columns), you could use both `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT 
                T.KeyColumn,
                E.Value Email
    FROM dbo.YourTable T
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Email,';') E
)
SELECT  KeyColumn,
        STRING_AGG(Email,';') Email
FROM CTE
GROUP BY KeyColumn
;
```

**UPDATE for SQL Server 2016:**

With no `STRING_AGG` you'll have to use one the old ways; for instance:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT 
                T.KeyColumn,
                E.Value Email
    FROM dbo.YourTable T
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Email,';') E
)
SELECT  t.KeyColumn,
        Email = STUFF(( SELECT ';' + CONVERT(varchar(255),Email)
                        FROM CTE
                        WHERE KeyColumn = t.KeyColumn
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM CTE t
GROUP BY t.KeyColumn
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm sorry this doesn't work, but I think should be very close. I'm tweaking it..

Comment: Looking at it twice, it doesn't seem to work because I'm still on SQL 16

Comment: @ichachan ah, well, yeah, no `STRING_AGG` then